# Flash fullscreen with dual monitors

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

How do I get the dimensions of the monitor the user is watching the video with if they have dual monitors?  If I use this --

```
mc_videoDisplay.height = (Capabilities.screenResolutionY - 26);
mc_videoDisplay.width = Math.floor(mc_videoDisplay.height * 16 / 9);
```

it's only using the primary monitor so it's all out of whack if they're watching on the extended monitor.

Thanks

Comment: Are you doing that after full screen mode has been activated?

Comment: yes, it's in my FullScreenEvent.FULL_SCREEN eventListener

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than getting the screen resolution from Capabilities, could you just use the stage width and height?

```
this.stage.stageWidth
this.stage.stageHeight
```

If you're going to do this, make sure to set the scaleMode to StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE or else the stageWidth and stageHeight will remain constant (and only the scale will change.)

From: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=05_Display_Programming_10.html :

> If the scaleMode property is set to
>   StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE, the Stage's
>   stageWidth and stageHeight properties
>   change to reflect the size of the
>   screen area occupied by the SWF (the
>   entire screen, in this case);

Comment: Thank you that worked.  You must get the stageWidth and stageHeight "beofre" going into fullscreen mode.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are targeting [FP10.2](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/890/cpsid_89050.html#main_mutliple%20monitors):

> ### Support for full screen mode with multiple monitors
>
> Full screen content will remain in
>   full-screen on secondary monitors,
>   allowing users to watch full-screen
>   content while working on another
>   display.

Then, `stageWidth` and `stageHeight` would work.